# LaTeX Template for Technical Books

Tags: templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for a technical reference manual / user guide?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/latex-template-for-a-technical-reference-manual-user-guide)

I’m looking for some good templates for technical books. I’m particularly interested in computer science. Please note that, I’m very new to LaTeX therefore, simple template would be helpful for me.

thanks

Comment: I would recommend you look at the memoir class.  Use http://www.texdoc.net/ to get quickly to the documentation.  Plenty of examples and the manual itself is a great example of a nicely formatted book suitable for computer science.

Comment: Additionally I would recommend that you search this site with the phrase `writing a book`.  Many useful results.