# Links of book templates

Tags: templates, r, books, report

[This report](http://secure.pensionsmyndigheten.se/download/18.76cf683d13f231c03cd1bc/Orange+Report+2012.pdf) is written by using R and Latex. I am kind of curious to see the Latex and R codes behind the generation of this excellent report.

Can anyone suggest me some links directing to excellent book or report template? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure, if the article you linked is really well designed. Of course it is really nice when you lay your eyes on, but with nearly 100 letters per line not easy to read.

Comment: Please, take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/latex-template-for-a-technical-reference-manual-user-guide

Comment: Just to begin: [LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/)