# Which LaTeX template to pick if I want to write a tutorial paper that would stay unpublished?

Tags: templates, journal-publishing, publishing, paper

Let's say that I'd like to write an unpublished tutorial paper like this one: https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01619

*Note: by "unpublished", I mean uploaded to ArXiV (and maybe also Google Scholar), but not sent to a journal nor to a conference.*

However, I don't want to start from scratch. **Which free and permissive template would you pick to achieve similar formatting results?**

I'd also like to kindly know your opinion on putting online unpublished papers in the case those papers could get a few citations.

Comment: Have you checked this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/latex-template-for-a-technical-reference-manual-user-guide ? 
I know an article is different from a long manual, but might be useful.

Comment: You can download the source of most of the arXiv papers and just see what styles your most favorite ones use. And I do not understand your last statement, there are many arXiv papers which have picked up tons of citations.

Comment: Using a template is no substitute for reading the manuals, especially amsmath and mathtools.

Comment: the full tex source is available at the link you gave, so what is your question?

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know LaTeX was provided on arXiv.

Comment: A very nice example (IMHO) of a good arXiv post is [A supersymmery primer](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9709356) by Steve Martin. If you download the source, you can adjust the conventions for the Minkowski metrics using LaTeX macros. According to the arXiv classification, this is unpublished, but it does have a significant number of citations.  (Whether or not I like the actually typesetting style is a different question, but one should also remember the original submission date.)

Comment: @marmot Your example has the capions too close to the figures, and the tables with vertical rules and no increased `\arraystretch`...

Comment: @CarLaTeX I agree, but I tried to explain why I was referring to this example: really very LaTeX user friendly as it allows one to change all conventions with just one LaTeX macro. And given that this was uploaded more than 20 years ago, I think one can forgive the author not using Ti*k*Z ducks. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Oh, more than 20 years ago!